# How to populate a picklist with it's label value instead of API value from class

Tags: picklist

Have the following code which populates field Code__c where null

```
List<Account> accounts = [
                    SELECT
                        Id, 
                        Code__c 
                    FROM 
                        Account 
                    WHERE 
                        Code__c = : null
                    LIMIT 4000
            ];
System.debug('accounts: ' + accounts);
for(Account acc : accounts){
    acc.Code__c = 'Some_Code__c';
}
update accounts;
```

After running I look at the account records that have been updated and they are showing the API Value 'Some_Code__c' instead of the Label Value 'Some Code'

How would i get the record to show the Label Value instead of the API Value?

Comment: in your example, what is `Some_Code__c` supposed to represent? As written, it's just a string of text and so that's what's getting stored in the `Code__c` field.

Comment: Instead of  acc.Code__c = 'Some_Code__c' you can do acc.Code__c = 'Some Code' and that change in literal would store the label but you should avoid hardcoding like this so use following instead \n SELECT toLabel(CUSTOM_PICK_LIST_COL__C) FROM YOUROBJ_C

Comment: @Mitesh The issue is i can only store a string of text that matches the API Value, in this case 'Some_Code__c'. I want to be able to store the Label Value 'Some Code' but when I try acc.Code__c = 'Some Code' i get an error saying not a picklist value

Answer (score 0):

Your code is literally putting the string of text 'Some_Code__c' into the field value because it is surrounded by single quotes.  The other comments are correct; you'll need to either change the string to the desired 'Some Code', or query for a desired picklist value from the database.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of the code?

Comment: You would just use the literal string 'Some Code' with no underscores.  It's technically possible for a picklist to have a different label versus the api value, but it's very rare.  (IE: I haven't seen it and I've logged on to roughly 150 orgs.)